# Find Multiple Patterns and Merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I find and sort in a new dataframe the following:

Input:

```
      IdA        IdB           Value
0     123        ABC_25_01     1
1     456        DEF_25_01     2
2     123        ABC_60_01     3
3     456        DEF_60_01     4
```

Output

```
      IdA        IdB      Value25 Value60
0     123        ABC_01   1       3
1     456        DEF_01   2       4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values in `IdB` are all in the form `X_Y_Z` where `X_Z` is the final `IdB` and `Y` is the Column header:

1. Use `str.extract` to get the "Category" i.e. the number between the two underscores
2. User `str.replace` to remove the "Category" from IdB.
3. `pivot` to get the required output

```
df["Category"] = df["IdB"].str.extract("_(.*)_")
df["IdB"] = df["IdB"].str.replace("_(.*)_", "_", regex=True)
output = (df.pivot(["IdA", "IdB"], "Category", "Value")
          .add_prefix("Value")
          .reset_index())

>>> output

Category  IdA     IdB  Value25  Value60
0         123  ABC_01        1        3
1         456  DEF_01        2        4
```